# -bash: solr: command not found in Mac

Tags: java, macos, bash, solr, lucene

I am trying to setup Apache Solr in my Mac. I am using Soler-5.5.0 version and Java 1.8. I am trying as per instructions.

I tried:

```
cd /users/ravi/dev/solr-5.5.0/bin
solr start
```

But I got error:

> -bash: solr: command not found

After, I tried:

```
cd /users/ravi/dev/solr-5.5.0/server
java -jar start.jar
```

I got error:

> WARNING: Nothing to start, exiting ...
>
> Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
>          java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information

How can I setup Solr in Mac?

Comment: you cd into `bin`, then try to run solr from the local directory `bin`. So unless there is a `bin` in the `bin` folder, then either move up a level, or just use `./solr`. Also i haven't used it for a while but im pretty sure you have to pass in the server arguments to the command.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the best way to tun Solr as service. Just below steps required:

1) download and extract Solr

2) Once run `sudo bash ./solr-6.5.0/bin/install_solr_service.sh solr-6.5.0.tgz`

3) The above command will setup the environment to run the Solr and start the Solr service.

4) Then play around the service with below commands:`sudo service solr status` , `sudo service solr restart`, `sudo service solr stop` , `sudo service solr start`

No further setup required and It's the recommended way for production.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I did a mistake that I have to do:

```
cd /users/ravi/dev/solr-5.5.0
./bin solr start
```

But I did

```
cd /users/ravi/dev/solr-5.5.0/bin
solr start
```

Anyway, it is working now.

Comment: This question should be closed if it's due to a simple typographic error. It will provide no value to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed via Homebrew you should just be able to run

```
solr start
```

and then to stop

```
solr stop
```

another thing you could try if you didn't install using homebrew is using cd to get into your solr directory and running

```
bin/solr start
```

The easiest way to troubleshoot this issue is by checking your bin directory to see if you even have solr mapped there. It looks as though solr isn't found in your bin directory (I could be wrong.  I'm just going off your error message).

EDIT:

If solr was installed as a service, you might have to use

`sudo service solr start`